# Probability of alternating sequence from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, approximation

Say I sample a discrete uniform distribution $U$ (say $U$ has a support of $N$ elements, and there is a total order on the elements) a number $K$ times, resulting in a random sequence $A_{i}$. What can I say about the probability that $A_{i}$ follows an alternating "up-down-up-down" pattern (or "down-up-down-up"), i.e. $A_{i} \ge A_{i+1} \mbox{ iff. } A_{i+1} \le A_{i+2}$ for all $i$?

Or, if there is a way to compute it exactly in my case $N = 20$ and $K = 18$. And, in my case $support(U) = {1,2,3,...N}$.

EDIT: Good approximations are OK.

Comment: You wrote "strictly alternating", then used weak inequalities and then accepted an answer that uses strict inequalities. Which one do you want?

Comment: In truth I assume the difference on the probability is not big enough to matter, I was assuming that the resulting bounds would be loose enough that it wouldn't change the equation. I suppose I would like weak inequalities. Strictly alternating is confusing, I suppose there is no other way to interpret alternating. I edited the question.

Comment: If you assume the difference isn't big enough to matter, does that mean we might as well assume a continuous distribution with a.s. different samples?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that would make a big difference at $N = 20,$ I suppose that makes sense to do.

Comment: Actually, with weak inequalities this probability is $\approx 5.3\times 10^{-4}$ versus $\approx 1.7\times 10^{-4}$ with $>$.

Comment: @d.k.o.: There seems to be something wrong -- the value for the continuous uniform distribution, where we simply count alternating permutations, should be between those two values -- but according to [OEIS sequence A001250](https://oeis.org/A001250) it's $\approx7.51\cdot10^{-4}$ (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler dynamic programming approach is to keep a single vector of counts of zig-zag sequences that ended at a certain value in, say, a down movement, and invert it in each update. Then with $a_{ki}$ denoting the number of zig-zag sequences of length $k$ ending in $i$ on a down movement, we have

$$
a_{k+1,N+1-i}=\sum_{j=1}^ia_{kj}
$$

(or with upper limit $i-1$ for strict inequality). Thus the update is described by a matrix of the form

$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0
}
$$

(or with zeros on the antidiagonal for strict inequality). We need to multiply by this matrix $K-1$ times, starting with initial values $a_{1i}=1$, then add all entries of the resulting vector and multiply by $2$ to also count zig-zag sequences ending in an up movement.

This is easily computed; the result, for $K=18$ and $N=20$, is $308129261694893525406$ for weak inequalities and $125294419211622187098$ for strict inequalities. ([Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/c2cc973f6f7fc386d1d6f934d453af72).)

Thus the probability of obtaining a zig-zag sequence is

$$
\frac{308129261694893525406}{20^{18}}=\frac{154064630847446762703}{131072000000000000000000}\approx1.18\cdot10^{-3}
$$

for weak inequalities and

$$
\frac{125294419211622187098}{20^{18}}=\frac{62647209605811093549}{131072000000000000000000}\approx4.78\cdot10^{-4}
$$

for strict inequalities.

For $N\to\infty$, we can replace the discrete distribution by a continuous one. Then we're simply counting the alternating permutations of $K$ elements. This is [OEIS sequence A001250](https://oeis.org/A001250) (the entry contains a lot of information about generating functions and the like), and the count for $K=18$ is $4809759350882$. Thus in this case the probability of obtaining a zig-zag sequence is

$$
\frac{4809759350882}{18!}=\frac{2404879675441}{3201186852864000}\approx7.51\cdot10^{-4}\;,
$$

which is approximately the geometric mean of the other two probabilities. For finite $N$, this corresponds roughly to having $\frac12$ on the antidiagonal, i.e. letting each equality count as a satisfied inequality with probability $\frac12$. This yields a probability of obtaining a zig-zag sequence of

$$
\frac{25601115678617843777394720}{20^{18}\cdot2^{17}}=\frac{160006972991361523608717}{214748364800000000000000000}\approx7.45\cdot10^{-4}\;.
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you derive the formula for advancing the $a$ to the next $K$? With your sum wouldn't that now count longer sequences that end on an 'up'? Oh I see so every iteration you switch between counting sequences ending on up or down based on whether K is even.

Comment: @BenjaminBraun: We have $a_{kj}$ sequences of length $k$ ending in $j$ on a down movement. Each of these can be extended to a sequence of length $k+1$ ending in $i\ge j$ on an up movement, and each of these extended sequences can be inverted to yield a sequence of length $k+1$ ending in $N+1-i$ on a down movement.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is even, the probability of "up-down-up..." pattern, i.e. for 
$$B=\{A_1<A_2,A_3<A_2\wedge A_4,\dots, A_{K-1}<A_{K-2}\wedge A_K\}$$

can be calculated as

$$
P\{B\}=\sum_{1\le a_2,a_4,\dots a_K\le N}P\{A_1<a_2\}\cdots P\{A_{K-1}<a_{K-2}\wedge a_K\}\prod_{i \text{ is even}}P\{A_i=a_i\} \\
=N^{-K}\sum_{1\le a_2,a_4,\dots a_K\le N}(a_2-1)(a_2\wedge a_4-1)\cdots(a_{K-2}\wedge a_K-1) .
$$

Similarly, for

$$C=\{A_1>A_2,A_3>A_2\wedge A_4,\dots, A_{K-1}>A_{K-2}\wedge A_K\}$$

$$
P\{C\}=N^{-K}\sum_{1\le a_2,a_4,\dots a_K\le N}(N-a_2)(N-a_2\vee a_4)\cdots(N-a_{K-2}\vee a_K) .
$$

Also, $B\cap C=\emptyset$.

---

For $N=20$ and $K=18$, $P\{B\}=P\{C\}\approx 2.39\times 10^{-4}$.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, how do I read the $\wedge$ operators in the very last line? I interpreted that as logical conjunction in the prior lines.

Comment: $a\wedge b$ means $\min\{a,b\}$

Comment: If I interpret the question correctly, this is half the probability that the question asked for.

Comment: @sinbadh thanks

Comment: @joriki I was a bit vague, I am interested in "down-up-down-up" sequences too, this only computes "up-down-up-downs" but I can multiply by two of course :)

Comment: Also did you compute $P\{B\}$ by brute force for $N = 20$ and $K = 18$? It seems like there would be $20^9$ possibilities which is not all that intractable but I am still curious.

Comment: @BenjaminBraun Yeah, 10 loops :) I wouldn't do it for larger $N$...

Comment: I think you swapped the roles of $K$ and $N$?

Comment: So he did, somehow I still followed

Comment: @BenjaminBraun: But that explains why the numbers differ -- they're actually for $N=18$ and $K=20$. I get the same numbers in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This describes a dynamic programming approach to compute it.

1) Come up with a $N \times N \times 2 \times 2 $ matrix $T_K$ so that $T_K[i][j][a][b]$ 
(where $i,j \in support(U), a,b \in \{down, up\}$)  is the probability a sequence of length $K$ being alternating AND starting with $i$, ending with $j$, and where the first change is $a$ and the last change is $b$ (this only makes sense if $K \ge 2$.) This can be done by hand somewhat easily.

Notation: $down^{-1} = up, up^{-1} = down.$

2) Let $K' = 2K - 1$ and we can then compute 
$$T_{K'}[i][j][a][b] = \sum_{k\in support(U),u \in\{down, up\}}{T_K[i][k][a][u] \cdot T_K[k][j][u^{-1}][b]}$$

3) Repeat step 2, this gives matrices for $K=2,3,5,9,17$ and 17 is close enough to what I want. Finally, sum over the elements of $T_{17}$ to compute the probability of any alternating sequence.